# How to update fileSystemWatch in order to find newly created file in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I have a console app which is checking a logfile for newly updated data, if yes, then copies them in a db.

Currently I'm using FileSystemWatcher to track any changes in the log.

What I would like to do is, to track if a `new` logfile is created, if yes, then to invoke myMethod() in the new logfile.
Since I'm new in C# I have a question, should a create a second fileSystemWatcher, or there's a way to update the current one in order to include also this case? I already checked stackoverflow and although I found many posts on fileSystemWatcher, I'm not really sure on how to proceed.
Here's my code:

```
foreach (string path in paths)
        {
            if (path.Length > 0)
            {
                logFile.read(path, errorListAndLevel);

                FileSystemWatcher logWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
                logWatcher.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
                logWatcher.Filter = Path.GetFileName(path);
                logWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
                logWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.CreationTime | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size;

                logWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(delegate (object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
                {
                    logFile.myMethod(errorListAndLevel, e.FullPath.ToString());

                });
                logWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
             }
         }
```

I thought of creating a logWatcher.Created... but it isn't working.

```
logWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(delegate (object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    logFile.myMethod(errorListAndLevel, e.FullPath.ToString());
});
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it? For me the code looks fine at a first glance

Comment: @RononDex ,  2 days now I'm trying but nothing, the logWatcher.Created is like it doesn't exist :/

Comment: And your changed() event is working fine?

Comment: @RononDex while debugging, yes it's working. I'm adding/removing lines to the logfile and it tracks the change. But the next step would be to track if a new file will be created (filename1.log, filename2.log etc)

Comment: @RononDex does it make sense to create a 2nd 
    FileSystemWatcher directoryFileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

with different NotifyFilters?

Comment: Can you try to remove the line `logWatcher.Filter = Path.GetFileName(path);`

Comment: Am I a dummy, or are you creating a local logWatcher per path in paths and loosing the references to it when you do the next path? I'd say that you allow the garbage collector to collect it?

Comment: @RononDex now it's working! Question: If i don't define the file name (logWatcher.Filter) will it track **ANY** file that will be created? Because I need to identify ONLY files whose names follow a specific pattern (filename1.log, filename2.log etc) .

Comment: @HaraldDutch you are right, actually it will be almost impossible to have more than 1 path simultaneously, i did it like that, just in case!

Comment: You can add a filter looking like this: `"*.log"`. This will only catch files with the extension ".log"

Comment: @RononDex thanks! If you want, put your answer below to mark it as best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the following line

```
logWatcher.Filter = Path.GetFileName(path);
```

It filters all files and makes the `fileWatcher` only whatch that one file. Now this makes the `fileWatcher` not calling the event `Created` unless a second a file with the exact same name will be created.

When you comment that line it should work fine.

Additionaly you could do this instead:

```
logWatcher.Filter = "*.log";
```

This will filter all files with the ending `.log` which is what you want from what I can see.

Comment: Is there a way to put a value in the logWatcher.Filter that it will search for a specified name format (filename1.log, filename2.log etc), to change for example the digit number?

Comment: You could try "filename*.log". Not sure if it will work though, havent tested it